# How can I write a form to input a list of text with ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, formtastic

I'm writing an ActiveAdmin form for a record which takes an Array of Strings. Let's call them widgets. I'm using a multi select form like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Things do
  permit_params widgets[]

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      ...
      f.input :widgets,
        as: :select,
        collection: [],
        multiple: true
    end
  end
end
```

With a bit of Javascript to help the user can enter their widgets and it will be delivered as an Array of Strings just fine. But when editing an existing record the existing `record.widgets` are not filled into the field, the widgets field is blank. I suspect what's happening is ActiveAdmin/Formtastic is interpreting this select as a has_many relationship with Widget, and the Strings as Widget IDs. ActiveAdmin is ignoring the failure.

How can I write an input to pass a plain Array of Strings into a model with ActiveAdmin? I'd like my parameters as `params[:thing][:widgets] = ["foo", "bar"]`

Answer (score 0):

By providing `collection: []`, you are telling the form to always start with blank array.

You need to provide the actual Thing's widgets to the form. You'll need to modify the example to play well with the select box / javascript you wrote - just bear in mind that collection takes an array - `collection: resource.widgets.split(',')`.